# Difference between selecting by color and selecting according to color

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

In a paper I read, the authors selected various images *by* color, and I wondered if what they did wouldn’t be better expressed by *according to* color. But the longer I thought about it, the less sure I was. Maybe someone here can help my muddled brain.

Answer (score 2):

Since *by* has a sense "according to", the meaning is the same.

The second is longer, and more cumbersome. That's not a difference in meaning, but it is a practical reason to favour the first.

Now, if a given use of *by* in this sense was open to misinterpretation to any of the other senses of *by*, that would be a reason to favour the latter. But since that seems unlikely, I'd go for the first.

Comment: Select or sort by colour... Sounds fine to me

Comment: @alwayscurious the only problem being that sometimes after doing a *lot* of sounding out, it can get to the point where *nothing* sounds normal!

Comment: @Jon Hanna: Indeed! That's why I find this site so useful... Thank you, also for your many other comments here.